# Different scaling mode

Tags: c#, winforms, scaling, dpi

I'm working on adaptation my WinForms application to scale when different DPI level is selected.
And i noticed one strange thing: when i'm using DPI 150% on Windows 8.1, my application looks like "stretched" 100% DPI application. On Windows 7 everything is fine, and on the same Win8.1 with 125% DPI everything is fine too.
Any ideas?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

SOLUTION:
Correct behavior was reached by adding the following content to application manifest:

```
 <asmv3:application>
    <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
        <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
    </asmv3:windowsSettings>
</asmv3:application>
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13228185/1997232).

Comment: I've found the solution in that thread, thank you!